# How to pass a value by url with unvisible in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I am passing a value by url in angular8. Not able to get the passing value from main component.Also id=2 will be visibl ein the url but gt should not visibile in the url.That's why i am using skipLocationChange. skipLocationChange=true is not working properly. So, How to resolve this issue?

header.component.ts:

```
  nextComp() {
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], { queryParams: { id: '2' } });
  this.router.navigate([], {
  relativeTo: this.route,
  queryParams: {
    gt: 'hc',
  },
  queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
  skipLocationChange: true,
  });
  }
```

main.component.ts:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((param: Params) => {
  console.log(param['id']);
  console.log(param['gt']);

  if(param['gt'] == 'dc'){
    alert("You are coming from dashboard component")
  }
  if(param['gt'] == 'hc'){
    alert("You are coming from header component")
  }

 }); 
 }
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
  nextComp() {
   this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], { queryParams: { id: '2' } }); 
   this.router.navigate([], {
   relativeTo: this.route,
   queryParams: {
    gt: 'dc',
   },
   queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
   skipLocationChange: true,
  });
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feature-modules-final-example-1mfbmx?file=app%2Fdashboard%2Fmain%2Fmain.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing `router.navigate` twice why you're not doing something like this,

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], { queryParams: { id: '2' , gt: 'dc'} });
```

and also where you have used ngAfterViewInit you forgot to implement AfterViewInit,

so add it,

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
```

Comment: Please check my question and try to edit my stackblitz?

Comment: @EMahanK https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feature-modules-final-example-eyjfa2 here you go.